# ISNUMERIC on VARCHAR Column returning numbers still?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, slash, isnumeric

Why does ISNUMERIC = 0 return numbers with spaces and '/' ? 
This is SQL Server 2008 R2 BTW

Thanks Guys,

Code Sample:

```
  SELECT A AS 'VARCHARCOLUMN' FROM TABLE
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(A) = 0

    TABLE Structure:
    ----------------------
        A  |   B    |   C   |
    ----------------------
      x    |        |       |
      .    |        |       |
      p    |        |       |
     1 7/2 |        |       |
     15.   |        |       |
      5    |        |       |


      Result set:
   ----------------------
        A  |   B    |   C   |
    ----------------------
      x    |        |       |
      p    |        |       |
     1 7/2 |        |       | <- Why is this returned???
```

Comment: Spaces are not valid in numbers.  Do you really find this surprising?

Comment: [All kinds of problems with `ISNUMERIC()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20051025015615/http://www.aspfaq.com/show.asp?id=2390), aside from the fact that spaces and slashes are not valid in a number, as others have explained. Store your numbers in one column and non-numeric values in another column, that eliminates much of this headache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IsNumeric function in SQL Server only returns true when the expression is a valid numeric type.  It doesn't understand that the expression is 1 and seven eighths.  It sees this as a string.   [MSDN IsNumeric Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Comment: Well, to be more precise, when the expression can be converted to any of the valid numeric types. Take `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1e2');` for example - this returns 1, but `SELECT CONVERT(INT, '1e2');` yields an error. Try `FLOAT` instead.

Comment: Got around this performing the following:
     SELECT A AS 'VARCHARCOLUMN' FROM TABLE
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(A,1,1)) = 0

Comment: Once you get up to SQL Server 2012, you might want to look into [`TRY_CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx), which is like `CAST` but will quietly return NULL instead of raising an error on a cast failure. This can make conversion code a bit more fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Because none of these are considered numeric.  The value '1 7/2' is not a numeric value - it is a string (the slash and the space are non-numeric).

Comment: The space is somewhat irrelevant.  `ISNUMERIC('    1    ')` evaluates to `1`.

Comment: I realize that, however the first character is a number would that not return in the result set due to this... perhaps my answer should be to parse the column to 1 character and then use ISNUMERIC... I will try this

Comment: @Gerrat I disagree. These both yield 0: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1 2'), ISNUMERIC(' ');` The fact that *outer* spaces are trimmed is what's irrelevant - the OP doesn't have outer spaces, they have spaces in the middle of the string, which are not the same thing.